# Angular 2+ Path in ErrorHandler error.stack

Tags: angular, error-handling, stack-trace, stacktrace.js

I'm trying to use stacktrace.js to report errors, but the path in the stack trace is referencing "*ng:///FormModule/MyComponent.ngfactory.js*"

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///FormModule/MyComponent.ngfactory.js:668:41)
    at handleEvent (http://localhost/dist/form/angular-vendor.bundle.js:12204:138)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost/dist/form/angular-vendor.bundle.js:13665:42)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost/dist/form/angular-vendor.bundle.js:13253:12)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost/dist/form/angular-vendor.bundle.js:8808:21)
    at http://localhost/dist/form/angular-vendor.bundle.js:9419:20
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/dist/form/angular-vendor.bundle.js:29309:53)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/dist/form/polyfills.bundle.js:7779:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost/dist/form/angular-vendor.bundle.js:4090:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/dist/form/polyfills.bundle.js:7778:36)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost/dist/form/polyfills.bundle.js:7546:47)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost/dist/form/polyfills.bundle.js:7841:38)
```

Stacktrace.js cannot locate the bundle file and it's corresponding source map because this path cannot be loaded

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ng:///FormModule/MyComponent.ngfactory.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Is anyone using WebPack, Stacktrace.js and getting the source maps to work, or does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed a similar issue in an Angular 6 project by passing `{offline: true}` as the second argument to `StackTrace.fromError` method as follows:

```
StackTrace.fromError(error, {offline: true}).then(...
```

As suggested [here](https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js/issues/127).